# Reference for Measurable Selection

Tags: reference-request, measurable-functions, multivalued-functions

Let $F(t,a):T\times A \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous in $a$ for each $t$ and measurable in $t$ for each $a$.
Is there  a selection theorem for the case
$$
I(t) = \{a\in A: F(t,a) = B(t)\}
$$
I found a reference where $B$ is a fixed closed subset. 
($F(t,a)\in B$ in that case)
However, I have $B(t)$ (single valued) depends on $t$.

(Spaces are as nice as possible.)

Comment: Is $B$ measurable? Then I guess you could probably apply your reference to $F(t,a)-B(t)$?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select? Are you looking for a function $f: T \to A$ with $f(t) \in I(t)$ for all $t$? What conditions do you need $f$ to satisfy? If you don't have any conditions, then $f$ exists by the Axiom of Choice, provided that $I(t)$ is not empty for any $t \in T$.

Comment: @user108903 Yes it is measurable, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I was looking for a measurable selection

Comment: Please edit your question to add all relevant information to it.